# How to attach functioning listener to Paste from ClipBoard event in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3, clipboard, paste

Adobe Livedocs page about Paste event on an [InteractiveObject](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/InteractiveObject.html#event:paste) has a note like this:

> TextField objects do *not* dispatch `clear`, `copy`, `cut`, `paste`, or
>   `selectAll` events. TextField objects always include Cut, Copy, Paste,
>   Clear, and Select All commands in the context menu. You cannot remove
>   these commands from the context menu for TextField objects. For
>   TextField objects, selecting these commands (or their keyboard
>   equivalents) does not generate `clear`, `copy`, `cut`, `paste`, or `selectAll`
>   events. However, other classes that extend the `InteractiveObject`
>   class, including components built using the Flash Text Engine (FTE),
>   will dispatch these events in response to user actions such as
>   keyboard shortcuts and context menus.

However we couldn't find any `InteractiveObject` at all that supports "Paste" event, including `Sprite`, `SimpleButton`, `TextLine`. Does anybody know what *other classes* Adobe is talking about in this paragraph?

Comment: There once was a [Text Layout Framework](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WSb2ba3b1aad8a27b0-1b8898a412218ad3df9-8000.html#WS14c3067b34b57c6d4a97343b122ab36a52f-8000) (utilized the FTE), It's now deprecated without any fulfilling alternative! Good old days!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering my own question here.

`SimpleButton` has worked in the end. Maybe I was doing something wrong the first time.